# Touch ID when “Sublime Text wants to make changes”

Tags: macos, security, touch-id

I figured out how to use Touch ID for [some changes](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/327025/touch-id-when-wants-to-make-changes).

But when I edit `/etc/hosts` with my Sublime Text, I still get this window:

[image]

How can I use Touch ID for messages like this?

Comment: I flagged as duplicate, you'll find your answer in the linked duplicate. Changing /etc/hosts needs you to have `sudo` permissions, thus the lock. With the accepted answer, you'll be able to use touch id for all `sudo` actions, such as editing `/etc/hosts`

Comment: @JeanRostan but for some reason it does not work. Just try it :)
It works for specific cases when dealing with terminal scripts, but not for Sublime Text or other applications.